# Using jsPlumb with Webpack React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack, jsplumb

I want to add `jsPlumb` to my webpack-build js-app(ReactJS). I'm using `jsPlumb v2.0.7`. When we bundle with `webpack` it was throwing error

> Uncaught TypeError: jsPlumb.getRenderModes is not a function.

I was able to resolve the above issue by using imports and script loader, my webpack config loader looks like,

```
{
    test: require.resolve('jsplumb'),
    loaders: [
      'imports?this=>window',
      'script'
     ]
 }
```

Now, I'm unable to access any of the `jsPlumb` methods, it couldn't be resolved by `webpack`. I get an error when i use ready method of `jsPlumb`

> Uncaught TypeError: _jsPlumb2.default.ready is not a function

`__jsPlumb2.default` is returning an empty object. Can someone let me know how to use `jsPlumb` with webpack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for the above mentioned issue, posting it here thinking that it might help someone else in future.

I had used ES6 import statement,

```
import jsPlumb from 'jsPlumb'
```

Instead, if I use

```
import jsplumb from 'jsplumb'
```

It resolved the problem and `jsPlumb` was available as global object since we used imports and script loader in webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the following ways works for me:

```
import jsPlumb from "jsPlumb"

import jsPlumb from "jsplumb/dist/js/jsplumb"

import jsPlumb from "jsplumb/dist/js/jsplumb.min"
```

However, before accessing its methods/properties, we should take a look at what jsPlumb consists of. When asserting console.log("jsPlumb :", jsPlumb) statement, we can see that jsPlumb consists of several properties; one of them is jsPlumb itself.
So, in order to access its methods/properties, we have to write like so :

```
jsPlumb.jsPlumb.someMethods
```

If we want a short syntax, we can set jsPlumb variable like so :

```
jsPlumb = jsPlumb.jsPlumb
```

Hence, we can use normal syntax to access its methods/properties :

```
jsPlumb.ready(function () {..})
jsPlumb.getInstance()
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you should use the following import statement to use a syntax as documented

```js
import { jsPlumb } from 'jsplumb';
```